# Get width and height during animation state

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm just wondering if it is possible to get the width and height of an element during animation state where height and width are animated? I'm using CSS3 to accomplish the animation. and I want to get it every 10 millisecond?

```
#animElement{
    -webkit-transition: width 1s, height 1s;
}
```

My javascript code is little bit wrong, could you take a look at it to? I'm testing to write the number i every 10 millisecond. I'm just testing this code for using it to get the width and height later.

```
for(var i=0;i<1000;i++){
    (function(num){
        window.setTimeout(function(){$('#flyingSquare').html(num);}, 10);
    })(i);
}
```

It wirtes the number 1000 directly which is wrong. It should count to 100 instead.

Comment: You can't get realtime information on the element while it's being animated, only the end state. If you tell us more about your use case we might be able to find a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JavaScript to do the animation you can more easily.

Comment: Do you know how to get the smooth animation then? It slows down when nearing end of animation state? 3:rd degree polynom?

Comment: Use Jquery for smooth animations with ease-in and ease-out.